# Como passar variável normalmente por valor através de referência?

Tags: c++, passagem-por-referência

Eu quero passar a variável `tabe` (que é do tipo `ifstream`) por referência para uma função (não quero uma cópia dela, apenas que a função a altere), pois bem, não entendi muito bem como se faz isso.

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


string apaga_espaco(ifstream* tabe)
{

string s;
char N;
while ((tabe*).good())
{
    getline((tabe*), s);
    s.erase(0,29);
    N=s.find(':');
    s.erase(0,N+6);
    return 0;
}

}

 int main()
{
    ifstream tabe;
    char N;

    tabe.open("Tabela.txt", ios::in);

    if (!tabe.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Arquivo nao encontrado, erro fatal!";
        exit(1);
    }

    apaga_espaco(*tabe);

}
```

Comment: Você quer passar por valor ou por referência? Se quer passar por valor, a cópia ocorrerá.

Comment: poisé, eu quero passar por valor, mas o compilador me retorna esse erro: 37 22 C:\Users\Roger\Desktop\classificar\main.cpp [Error] no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}')

Comment: Que erro é mostrado?

Comment: [Error] no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}')

Comment: Eu vi que você aceitou as duas respostas. Não sei se percebeu, você só pode aceitar. Então quando você aceita a segunda, você tira da primeira. Não tem problema algum escolher qualquer uma delas, mas o ideal é escolher qual você achou melhor. Se é esta mesmo que você escolheu, ok, Mas se ela ficou aceita por acidente, você pode trocar a aceitação. Veja o [tour].

Comment: Sou novo por aqui, como as duas me ajudaram achei que podia escolher ambas, mas já arrumei, valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vou olhar para todo seu código para ver se tem mais erros. Se deu para entender o que você quer fazer é passar por referência. Então basta declarar o tipo do parâmetro como uma referência. O resto funciona de forma natural. Não precisa usar ponteiros.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void apaga_espaco(ifstream& tabe) {
    string s;
    char N;
    while (tabe.good()) {
        getline(tabe, s);
        s.erase(0, 29);
        N = s.find(':');
        s.erase(0, N + 6);
    }
}

int main() {
    ifstream tabe;
    char N;
    tabe.open("Tabela.txt", ios::in);
    if (!tabe.is_open()) {
        cout << "Arquivo nao encontrado, erro fatal!";
        exit(1);
    }
    apaga_espaco(tabe);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/FileName.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

A maioria das pessoas que programam em c++ passaram antes por C, porém c++ tem algumas particularidades, e uma delas é a passagem por referencia. no codigo em C para podermos alterar o valor da variável original nos temos que passar o ponteiro como parâmetro na função, porém em C++ basta que a gente passe o endereço dessa variável que ela será alterada, e dentro da nossa função podemos trabalhar com a variável como se estivéssemos trabalhando apenas com uma cópia, mas na verdade estamos alterando a variável original.
então em vez da assinatura da função ser assim

```
string apaga_espaco(ifstream * tabe)
```

basta que seja assim

```
void apaga_espaco(ifstream & tabe)
```

onde o & significa que voce está passando o endereco de memoria de tabe. 
uma coisa que me deixou confuso foi você declarar uma função que retorna uma string e retornar 0 no final. :(

Comment: Ela era bool mas depois eu troquei a esqueci de arrumar, kk